# How to create encoded AVPacket without sending frame to the encoder?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I have a raw_pixels of YUV_240 that I can supply to the encoder using `avcodec_send_frame` but is it possible to encode raw AVPacket without sending it to the encoder?

I need this to parallelise encoding as much as possible but supplying raw frames only possible when frames are in correct order and we can not store all the raw data in memory.

I checked [av_packet_from_data](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavc__packet.html#ga7ca877e1f0ded89a27199b65e9a077dc) but it required already encoded data.

Comment: What does it mean to "encode raw AVPacket without sending it to the encoder"? Do you want to encode it yourself, outside of the ffmpeg library? Or do you want to figure out a way to pack the raw data into an AVPacket structure without any encoding in a way that doesn't break the stream (essentially, use a null encoding scheme)?

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov I have pixel data for each frame and all I need is to parallel the encoding of this raw images with ffmpeg, so the idea is exactly to "pack the raw data into an AVPacket structure without any encoding in a way that doesn't break the stream".

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear for me what you want to achieve.

If your pixel data is already encoded (e.g. GOP = 30, you should have 1 I-frame and 29 B/P-frames) than it is possible. See below example snippet.

Is your pixel data are full pictures it makes no really sense to write them without encoding because your GOP size would be 1 and you won't take advantage of compression.

This example just configures a package. The magic is done in 'av_interleaved_write_frame'.

```
AVPacket* pPacket = av_packet_alloc();

pPacket->data = data;
pPacket->size = sizeOfData;
pPacket->stream_index = 0;
pPacket->dts = frameCounter;

if(isIFrame)
{
    m_avPacket->flags = AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
}

av_interleaved_write_frame(pAvFormatContext, pPacket)
av_packet_free(&pPacket);
```

Note: I just tested this with simple AVI and H264.